# Fatal exception: main when adding imageview

Tags: android, eclipse

My app runs fine with just text, but when I add an image I get errors. This is what I get:

```
12-29 20:16:53.105: D/dalvikvm(1515): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 51% free 2665K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 2ms
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/GraphicsJNI(1515): VM won't let us allocate 23970816 bytes
12-29 20:16:53.105: D/skia(1515): --- decoder->decode returned false
12-29 20:16:53.105: D/AndroidRuntime(1515): Shutting down VM
12-29 20:16:53.105: W/dalvikvm(1515): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb6feb4f0)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lanaux.play.awesome/lanaux.play.awesome.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at lanaux.play.awesome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): ... 11 more
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): ... 22 more
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:118)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:108)
12-29 20:16:53.105: E/AndroidRuntime(1515): ... 25 more
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />


    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
    android:src="@drawable/christmas2" 
    android:contentDescription="happy holiday"/>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This may not fix the problem but replace `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"` with `android:layout_below="@id/textView1".` The variable `textView1` is already created.

Comment: Which line is #17 of the xml? if it's 'android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"' then I think @Szymon 's answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Just noticed it the logcat line `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. What is the image you are trying to load? Check your drawable `christmas2`. You may have a problem with it.

Comment: Your drawable christmas2 is definitely very large in size. try replacing it with a smaller size image.(image size and not the dimensions of the image)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
```

Points to the problem. At a guess, you have an error in you XML at line 17, however, I really think this is the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Which means you are trying to add an image which is too big for the device. You will need to resize the image first with something like `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` or `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`. There is a lot more info on handling larger images on the [Android Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) page.